# Filter something that is not number or specific letter from character vector

Tags: regex, r

I have a character vector called:

```
myvec<- c("122","112","ghtt1","fff","223F","X","Y")
```

How can I filter and get only numbers, 'X' and 'Y' as in the

Expected output:

```
122,112,X,Y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
grep("^([0-9]+|X|Y)$", myvec, value=TRUE)
#[1] "122" "112" "X"   "Y"
```

Comment: Thank you, what does `value=TRUE` indicate here?

Comment: @MAPK If you don't use that, `grep` returns the numeric index of the element it matches and then you have to subset it i.e. `myvec[grep("^([0-9]+|X|Y)$", myvec)]`.  By using `value=TRUE`, it returns the value instead of the index.

Answer (score 2):

We could also define fixed lookup list, then match.

```
# messy chromosome names:
myvec <- c("1","12","ghtt1","fff","22","X","Y")

# result
myvec[ which(myvec %in% c(1:22,"X","Y")) ]
# [1] "1"  "12" "22" "X"  "Y"
```